# I need to get info from HTML table , java

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to create a program that will read a table in a specific website and can get from it the data I need.
I read about the jsoup and elements and tried to implement what I read but something is missing for me
My table is HTML code is

```html
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="980px;">
<!-- START WARRANTY RESULTS  -->

<!-- START warrantyResultsDetails -->
<table class="ibm-data-table" summary="Warranty results" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<caption><b>Warranty information</b></caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">Type</th>
<th scope="col">Model</th>
<th scope="col">Serial number</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>8205</td>
<td>E6C</td>
<td>06202ET</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">Warranty status</th>
<th scope="col">Expiration date</th>
<th scope="col">Location</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>


Out of warranty <img src="//1.www.s81c.com/i/v17/icons/_icons/ibm_icon_blue_close.png" alt="" align="middle" height="16" width="16">

</td>
<td>2015-12-26</td>
<td>ISRAEL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<b>Warranty description</b>
<br>
This product has a 3 year limited warranty and is entitled to CRU (customer replaceable unit) and On-site labor repair service for selected parts.  On-site Service is available Monday - Friday, except holidays, with a next business day response objective.  A service technician will be scheduled to arrive at the customer's location on the business day after remote problem determination.
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col" colspan="3">Additional agreement</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<b>
This web site provides standard warranty or eServicePac information, please consult your local IBM representative or your reseller for other maintenance services or warranty information specific to your IBM Machine.
</b>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
<!-- END warrantyResultsDetails -->

<!-- END PARTS -->
</td>
</tr>
```

I tried to use a code that was written here in stackover but couldn't modify it correct

```js
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "https://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/wlup?type=8205&serial=06202ET";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        String question = document.select("#ibm-data-table").text();
        System.out.println("Question: " + question);

        Elements answerers = document.select("#answers .user-details a");
        for (Element answerer : answerers) {
            System.out.println("Answerer: " + answerer.text());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is another code that gives me all the data but still I want to get a specific ones from the table and not all of them

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class TableEg {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String html = "https://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/wlup?type=8205&serial=06202ET";
            
      try {
         Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
         Elements tableElements = doc.select("table");

         Elements tableHeaderEles = tableElements.select("thead tr th");
         System.out.println("headers");
         for (int i = 0; i < tableHeaderEles.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(tableHeaderEles.get(i).text());
         }
         System.out.println();

         Elements tableRowElements = tableElements.select("tr");

         for (int i = 0; i < tableRowElements.size(); i++) {
            Element row = tableRowElements.get(i);
            System.out.println("row");
            Elements rowItems = row.select("td");
            for (int j = 0; j < rowItems.size(); j++) {
               System.out.println(rowItems.get(j).text());
            }
            System.out.println();
         }

      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a Java dev really, but here goes...

In your final loop, you have 'rowItems', which is a list of all td elements on the screen - so now you need a way to reliably search this data for the bits of data you want. I'm guessing you will not have control over these tables, so you can't just simply set an id on the td's you're tracking so you can search by id.

If the format always stays the same, figure out how to pull the items in 'rowItems' by index. Index should be the same data whenever you return. Hopefully that'll point you in the right direction!

Comment: May you please explain what do you mean by "Not a Java dev really, but here goes..."?
As well can you show an example for what you are saying ?